# How to Disable Directory listing spring MVC war application, deployed on IBM WAS?

Tags: java, spring, security, websphere, directory-listing

Images, Css files are getting listed when we hit the URL

- domain/resources/img
- domain/resources/css

in ibm-web-ext.xml tried

```xml
<enable-directory-browsing value="false"/>
<enable-file-serving value="true"/>
```

in mvc dispatcher servlet

```xml
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Should block the directory listing of files.

Comment: Do you have an HTTP server also in front of WebSphere? Based on what you're showing, I don't think it's WebSphere or Spring that is allowing directory browsing.

Comment: @dbreaux Yes its the "IBM HTTP Server"